# Delphi - How to add a record to an existing treenode

Tags: delphi, treeview

I have an existing TreeView where the nodes were created with using 
`TreeView1.Items.Add(Nil,'abc');` (Ie. No Data Objects added)

I would like to add a Record to each of the Nodes to store some data with each Node.

Is there any way to that ??

Comment: But when the nodes were created there was no pointer added

Comment: You can access the new node through the TreeView. And then you can add Data.

Answer (score 4):

Define your own types. This is based on Delphi7 Help.

```
type
  PItemRecord = ^TItemRecord;
  TItemRecord = record
     Text: string;
  end;
```

Working example:

```
unit FMainTree;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ComCtrls;

type
  PItemRecord = ^TItemRecord;
  TItemRecord = record
     Text: string;
  end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    tree: TTreeView;
    ButtonAdd: TButton;
    procedure ButtonAddClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.ButtonAddClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   i: Integer;
   pdata: PItemRecord;
   node: TTreeNode;
begin
   // Add nodes without 'Data'
   tree.Items.Add(nil, 'Item1');
   tree.Items.Add(nil, 'Item2');
   tree.Items.Add(nil, 'Item3');
   // Add 'Data'
   for i := 0 to tree.Items.Count-1 do begin
      node := tree.Items[i];
      New(pdata);
      pdata^.Text := 'Text for node ' + node.Text;
      node.Data := pdata;
   end{for};
   // Show 'Data' for second item
   ShowMessage(PItemRecord(tree.Items[1].Data)^.Text);
end;

end.
```

Notes:

It is good practice to destroy the memory that is allocated with New(), although this memory is freed on program exit. This can be done in TreeView's OnDeletion event:

```
procedure TForm1.treeDeletion(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode);
begin
   Dispose(PItemRecord(Node.Data));
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Zhorov's answer works just fine, it could lead to memory leak if used improperly.

That is, if you allocate a record with `New`, you have to make sure that record will be freed before deleting the tree node.

Instead of using records, I would assign objects of a custom class to the Data property of the node and keep track of the objects with an [`TObjectList`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Contnrs_TObjectList.html) to make sure that they are properly destroyed when the form (or the application) is closed.

Here is a modified version of Zhorov's code:

```
unit FMainTree;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ComCtrls, Contnrs;

type
  TMyItem = class
  private
    FText: string;
  public
    property Text: string read FText write FText;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    tree: TTreeView;
    ButtonAdd: TButton;
    procedure ButtonAddClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FItemList: TObjectList;
  public
    procedure AfterConstruction();
    procedure BeforeDestruction();
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure AfterConstruction();
begin
  inherited;
  // `True` = automatically destroy items when deleted from the list or the list is destroyed
  FItemList := TObjectList.Create(True); 
end;

procedure BeforeDestruction();
begin
  // Destroying the list will also destroy the object items inside
  FItemList.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TForm1.ButtonAddClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   i: Integer;
   objData: TMyItem;
   node: TTreeNode;
begin
  // Add nodes without 'Data'
  tree.Items.Add(nil, 'Item1');
  tree.Items.Add(nil, 'Item2');
  tree.Items.Add(nil, 'Item3');

  // Add 'Data'
  for i := 0 to tree.Items.Count-1 do begin
    node := tree.Items[i];

    objData := TMyItem.Create();
    try
      objData.Text := 'Text for node ' + node.Text;
    finally
      FItemList.Add(objData);
    end;

    node.Data := objData;
  end{for};

  // Show 'Data' for second item
  ShowMessage(TMyItem(tree.Items[1].Data).Text);
end;

end.
```

I've intentionally used the non-generic version of [TObjectList](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Contnrs_TObjectList.html) (from Contnrs unit) as you have not specified the Delphi version you have, so it might have no generics. But if you do have Delphi 2009 or newer consult the following article for examples on how to use that instead: [Generics Collections TObjectList (Delphi)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Tokyo/en/Generics_Collections_TObjectList_(Delphi)):

> ```
> ...
> var
>   List: TObjectList<TNewObject>;
>   Obj: TNewObject;
> begin
>   { Create a new List. }
>   { The OwnsObjects property is set by default to true -- the list will free the owned objects automatically. }
>   List := TObjectList<TNewObject>.Create();
>
>   { Add some items to the List. }
>   List.Add(TNewObject.Create('One'));
>   List.Add(TNewObject.Create('Two'));
>
>   ...
>
>   List.Free;
> end.
> ...
> ```

Of course using objects instead of records would consume more memory, and if you have thousands of nodes, that could affect performance.

Comment: One can descend from the tree node class (and use the `OnCreateNodeClass` event for setting up the tree). Your proposal is fine (separating data from the presenter), but could fit better for a virtual tree.

Comment: @Victoria I agree, just an addition. If one decides to use the `OnCreateNodeClass` event and a subclass of `TTreeNode` instead of the `Data` property, one should take care not to store state in the node, as nodes can be subtly destroyed and recreated by the window manager when the TreeView is shown/hidden. A similar situation is discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837005/problem-subclassing-ttreenode-in-delphi